# Animation in pageViewer

Tags: android

I have in my project pageViewer where I show photos. How can I automatically slide to next photo? I want to after 2 second my page change on the next photo. This is any solution to this in android or I should create animation?
I try this:

```
    final int i=0;
    while(i < adapter.getCount() ){
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
    }
},2000);
    i++;
    }
```

but my `i` must be final and I don't know how I can setCurrentItem always i+1 to show next photo. Any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: Check out these links for more info : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077944/auto-scroll-images-after-2-seconds-in-viewpager-by-pageadapter ; 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847959/automatically-scroll-in-pageviewer