# Automatically scroll in PageViewer

Tags: android

I have a problem with pageviewer. I want to my page scroll every two seconds. I try something like this:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1, true);

    } 
},2000);
```

But it works only when I start activity. If i put this code to `public void onPageSelected(int page)` it works but I want to do when I click and manually scroll page I want to stop this handler but it doeasn't work. How I can do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should define your Runnable and Handler like this:

```
private boolean pagerMoved = false;
private static final long ANIM_VIEWPAGER_DELAY = 2000;

private Handler h = new Handler();
    private Runnable animateViewPager = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (!pagerMoved) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem()+1, true);
                h.postDelayed(animationFrame, ANIM_VIEWPAGER_DELAY);
            }
        }
    };
```

Make sure that you setup and tear down in your onPause & onResume methods

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (h != null) {
            h.removeCallbacks(animateViewPager);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        h.postDelayed(animateViewPager, ANIM_VIEWPAGER_DELAY);
    }
```

Finally, you'll need to listen for a touch event on your viewpager so that you can set pagerMoved to true (which will then stop further automatic page transitions).

Comment: can I slow sliding pictures, because when I swipe finger it looks great but when I use this way this is too fast. I would like to see this animation when first photo swipe on second. This is possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible, you need to look at the fakePageDrag methods on ViewPager

Comment: Can I just ask, is animationFrame inside the Runnable supposed to read animateViewPager?

Comment: Where do i need to add the above snippet ? can you please let me know ?

Comment: @user2056563 directly within your Activity (or Fragment)

Comment: @RussWheeler yes it is.