# ViewPager AutoScroll not Working Properly

Tags: android, timer, android-viewpager, autoscroll

Android ViewPager AutoScroll not working  properly  using scheduleAtFixedRate.

this is my code,is it right ?

```
  protected void startAutoScroll() {
    swipeTimer=new Timer();
    swipeTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(currentPosition==shalomBannersList.size())
                    {
                        currentPosition=0;
                    }

                        viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPosition,true);

                    currentPosition=currentPosition+1;

                }
            });

        }
    }, 100, 4000);

}
```

please help me.

Comment: I plugged your code into a pager I have.  I see the auto-scroll.  What is not working for you?

Comment: Have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847959/automatically-scroll-in-pageviewer

Comment: #qbix, it is scrolling.. but scrolling position is not correct... 1 to 3 to 1 to 2.. like moving... not 0,1,2.3...

Comment: Maybe a problem in your pager adapter?  You should add a log statement to the code you posted to observe the value of `currentPosition` change.  When you get this working, don't forget to add code to cancel the timer at the appropriate times, for example configuration change.  It doesn't get cancelled automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
int page=0;
public void pageSwitcher() {

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new RemindTask(), 1000, 3000);
}

class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (page > bannersList.size()) {
                    page = 0;
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(page++);
                } else {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(page++);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this library-

**Android Auto Scroll ViewPager**

ViewPager which can auto scrolling, cycling, decelerating.

ViewPager which can be slided normal in parent ViewPager.

[Git Link](https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager)[image]

**Following are the features -**

startAutoScroll() start auto scroll, delay time is getInterval().

startAutoScroll(int) start auto scroll delayed.

stopAutoScroll() stop auto scroll.

setInterval(long) set auto scroll time in milliseconds, default is DEFAULT_INTERVAL.

setDirection(int) set auto scroll direction, default is RIGHT.

setCycle(boolean) set whether automatic cycle when auto scroll reaching the last or first item, default is true.

setScrollDurationFactor(double) set the factor by which the duration of sliding animation will change.

setSlideBorderMode(int) set how to process when sliding at the last or first item, default is SLIDE_BORDER_MODE_NONE.

setStopScrollWhenTouch(boolean) set whether stop auto scroll when touching, default is true.

setBorderAnimation(boolean) set whether animating when auto scroll at the last or first item, default is true.