# Auto scroll images after 2 seconds in ViewPager by pageadapter

Tags: android

I am create a imagescroll view. There is two activity in images. first user can scroll to image which is working fine. and second auto-scroll images after 2 second. i tried a number of example but i am unable to do it . so i am posting here .

please android expert check it.

I am using it for scrolling image.

```
MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter();
        final ViewPager myPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        myPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


private class MyPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

        public int getCount() {
            return homescreenList.size();
        }

        public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
         try {
            LinearLayout images = new LinearLayout(collection.getContext());

               ImageView image = new ImageView(collection.getContext());
               image.setPadding(20, 0, 20, 0);  

            images.addView(image);

            ((ViewPager) collection).addView(images, 0); }
            return images;
         } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println("error:"+e.toString());
            }

            return position;
        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You want to scroll the `ViewPager` delayed by 2 seconds, right?

Two things you need for that:

- Wait for two seconds, by calling your code delayed with [`View.postDelayed(..., 2000L)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed)
- Scroll to the right position by [`View.scrollBy()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#scrollBy) or `scrollTo()`

Remark: I think the links do not point to the exact position. You must search on the web page for the method like `scrollBy`, `scrollTo` or `postDelayed`.

Comment: yes i want delayed by 2 seconds. but it should be AUTO-SCROLL and there is already also a manual scroll. so both should be work.

Comment: Not clear to me what you mean by auto-scroll. If it is automatically initiated by Android than it's a reaction to users activity like panning or flinging. Do you want to delay Androids reaction by 2 seconds? That would mean that the user thinks his system is just slow an does not react. Please explain further.